# Adding UL or OL to an HTML class

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm working on a WebHelp project with a CSS attached.  When Word documents are converted to topics then the corresponding CSS styles convert the Word documents to ready formatted HTML topics, except for the bulleted and numbered headings.  Is there a way to attach the UL and/or OL tags to a class, so that the numbered and bulleted levels will format automatically when a document is converted? I've seen references to JQuery on this topic.  I do not know JQuery but assume from the name that conditional statements could be created that automate some coding. I'm swinging in the dark there. However, I will pick it up (JQuery) if needed.

Here's an example of the code that I would add OL tags to:

```
<p class="Step">1.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;On the Insert tab, in the Illustrations group, click <span class="Commandtext">Shapes</span>.</p>
<p class="Step">2.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;Choose the shape you want to insert.</p>
<p class="Step">3.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;Click and drag to draw the shape on your slide.</p>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you show us some code? Maybe try explaining your problem in simpler terms? Also, I would suggest learning jQuery. It is very simple and very easy to pick up.

Comment: _"attach the UL and/or OL tags to a class"_ You mean add a class to all `ul` and `ol` elements? That is a trivial task using jQuery, though I'm not familiar with the platform(?) you're using, so I wouldn't know how to go about adding the code.

Comment: Simple as `$("ol").addClass("myClass");` if the above comment is correct.

Comment: Here is an example of some code that I adding OL tags to:

Comment: <p class="Step">1.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;On 
 the Insert tab, in the Illustrations group, click <span class="Commandtext">Shapes</span>.</p>
<p class="Step">2.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;Choose 
 the shape you want to insert.</p>
<p class="Step">3.<span style="font: 7.0pt 'Times New Roman';">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>&#160;Click 
 and drag to draw the shape on your slide.</p>

Comment: This is how it comes over when converted from Word; however, if I had a CSS style (or Class) that had OL attached to it then could the tags be properly placed within the HTML document?

Comment: @Jason, next time add the code in the question itself. Much easier to read :)

Comment: OK.  First time User, so the feedback is good. Thx.

Comment: @Jason do you want to replace the `<p class="Step>` elements with `ol`s, or do you want the css to make those `p` elements look like `ol`s? I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you're after.

Comment: I would like the CSS to make those P elements look like OL.

Comment: Where would I place this statement:   
Simple as $("ol").addClass("myClass"); if the above comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content in a `li` item, then remove the `p` tags. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ExT8j/ .
Updated version(cleaned bullets and removes span with empty spaces): http://jsfiddle.net/ExT8j/1/